# access the node id of a field collection

Tags: 8, entities

How do I access the node id of a d8 field collection that is attached to the node in  hook_preprocess_field(&$variables)?

Comment: If `$variables` contains already loaded Field Collection Item, then did you tried doing `$fc->getHostId()`, this should return the parent Node ID. **Assuming that `$fc` is your Field Collection Item object.**

Answer (score 1):

It works for me. You can do it as follows-

`/**
 * Function hook_preprocess_field.
 */
function [theme_name]_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['field_name'] == [FIELD_COLLECTION_NAME]) {
    if ($variables['element']['#entity_type'] == "node") {
      $node_id = $variables['element']['#object']->id();
      //Rest of the code.
    }
  }
 }`

Hope it works for you too.